# Displaying * in a table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables. One called users & the other called tv shows. The users table has: users_id, displayname, username and password, I have a foreign key called users_id and in the tv shows table I have tv_id, users_id FK, tvshow, seasons. I want to be able to display the displayname from the users table as to who created it rather than displaying the number id he is assigned.

Comment: Please don't build new applications with the deprecated `mysql_query` interface. It's terribly difficult to use correctly and can lead to severe problems if you're not extremely careful.

Comment: @tadman: not only the security issues will put the OP in a spot of bother here: since he's using FK's, I take it he's using InnoDB storage engine and might be using stored procedures, triggers or FK constraints. `mysql_*` simply doesn't support the features his Storage engine brings to the party...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following SQL query to fetch information about the user:

```
SELECT          users.username,
                tv_shows.*
    FROM        tv_shows
    LEFT JOIN   users
    ON          users.users_id = tv_shows.user_id
```

And then display the information about the user using the following PHP snippet:

```
 echo '<td>'.
      '<a href="users.php?username='.
      $row['username'].
      '">'.
      $row['username'].
      '</a></td>';
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! if i were to then the link with the username how would i display the results for that specified user? on my users.php i have     if(!$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tvshows WHERE user_id='$client'")) {

Answer (score 0):

Since your tv_shows table doesn't have a column with the name of 'username' it obviously doesn't work. So you need to fetch all fields you want to use with your SQL statement:

```
SELECT tv_shows.*, users.username
  FROM tv_shows
  JOIN users ON users.user_id = tv_shows.user_id
```

Depending on your table structure you might want to use `LEFT JOIN` instead...

Then you can use `$row['username']` in your PHP code, cause you fetched it with SQL before.

And I think you would need to brush up on some SQL tutorials to learn about joins, groupings, etc. The [SQL tutorial of W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp) is a nice point to start.